# What are the best ways of adding Loader / Spinner in Angular 2/4/5 application

Tags: angular

I want a common loading image for every time the app is processing some DOM manipulation or a service query. What are the best ways of doing the same thing.

1) Creating a component is common way. i want to know what all ways you can add a spinner.

i just want to know is there multiple ways to do it ??

Answer (score 1):

create a component (loader component) and import it and any component you need and you can just call loader component functions(show, hide)

Comment: that is one way of doing it . I want to know multiple ways

Comment: you haven't tried either way, you have to include some code in question what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a loader Component, and call it on some boolean value

Here's Example

HTML

```
<section class="InterimLoader" *ngIf="isLoading">
    <div class="loaderParent">
     //use a spinner icons or image
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section.InterimLoader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: transparent;
}

section.InterimLoader div.loaderParent{
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

section.InterimLoader .fa{
    font-size: 7em !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'loader',
    templateUrl: './loader.component.html'
})
export class ObsLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() isLoading: boolean;

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And you can call it in any component where you want the loader

```
<loader [isLoading]="isLoading"></loader>
```

`isLoading` defined the condition if you want to have the loader or not

Comment: Any other way ?

Comment: yeah so many, i'll tell you when this answer receives 5 upvotes